# 2 Worker Roles in one Azure Package

Tags: azure, azure-packaging

I have two worker roles in one Azure package.
I am getting this error:

> The port '3389' is used by both endpoint Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.RdpInput in role WorkerRole1 and  endpoint Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.RdpInput in role WorkerRole2.

But I dont find any reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.RdpInput in cloud service configuration(cscfg) file

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Verify that only one of the WorkerRoles has "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.Enabled" setting in the service configuration.  If both of them have this setting I believe the plug in will attempt set up the endpoint for both of them.  You only need one of the roles to serve as a remote forwarder.  From there it tunnels the remote access to any of the other roles that have the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled set to true.

If this is the case it should be giving you an error if you attempt to package or publish.

Comment: +1 Microsoft should really do a better job of making this stuff more explanatory - rather than the obscure message they output, perhaps something like "*You can only have `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder` enabled on one role within a project*".

Comment: You also have to remove <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" /> of the second worker role in the csdef file